# Why is my LTspice simulation taking so long?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, 555

I'm simulating an audio amplifier circuit in LTspice, using an opamp and 555 timer, based on the circuit I found [here.](https://www.electronicshub.org/low-power-audio-amplifier-using-555-timer/)

This is the circuit diagram and output:

[image: audio amplifier circuit and output]

As seen below, the transient analysis is progressing very slowly. I need an audio sample (from the output) of at least 5s. But even after leaving it for 20 minutes or so, the transient analysis only progressed to 3%.

I tried using some commands the [LTwiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F), but it's not helping much.

I had made this circuit using a BJT earlier. It didn't take too long to simulate then, although the output wasn't that great.

I had built opamp circuits using the same opamp, and it simulated fine. It's just this circuit with the 555 timer.

How do I speed up the simulation?

Comment: The "out" node is hanging with no DC path to ground - you may want to add an e.g. 100k resistance from that to GND.

Comment: I tried that now. But it still is taking a lot of time. I'll have to check if I made a mistake while copying the original circuit.

Comment: My best guess is that you are trying to use the 555 in a way in which its not modeled for (audio amplifier)

Comment: oh ok, I'll have to look into some other audio amplifier designs then.

Comment: C2 is too small by a factor of 1000 (10 pF when it should be 10nF.)  The diagram you followed shows 10pF, but the text says 10nF.  That makes the operating frequency of the oscillator some tens of MHz instead of the intended 145kHz.  Fix the capacitor and the simulation will speed up drastically.

Comment: This is a problem specific to this circuit.  I don't think the question should have been closed.  The linked question doesn't touch on the cause of the slow simulation that this question has.  The slow simulation here is because the circuit is running at an unexpectedly high frequency due to an incorrect component value.

Comment: oh damn, thanks a lot @JRE. You're right, the simulation is much faster now.

Comment: @JRE shoot you're right.